# shortcode to show custom post types by category

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to create a list of my post types separated by custom category

ie

```
Tax
 Cpt2
 cpt3
Tax2
 Cpt1
 Cpt4
Tax3
 Cpt5
```

I was hoping to do this through a shortcode, but keep getting an end of file error.  I'm definitely missing something.  Can i only run this code from an archive page?

Here is my code

```
function dhp_performersbycat() {
  //start by fetching the terms for the performer_category taxonomy
  $terms = get_terms( 'performer_category', array(
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'hide_empty' => 0
    ) );
  $catlist = '';
  // now run a query for each term
  foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    // Define the query
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'dhp_performers',
      'performer_category' => $term->slug
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

      $catlist .= '<div class="performercatlist"><h1>' . $term->name . '</h1>';

      // Start the Loop
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        $catlist .= '<h2>'.the_title().'</h2>';
        $i++;
      endwhile;

      // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
      wp_reset_postdata();
      $catlist .= '</div>'; 
  }
  return $catlist;
}
```

Comment: you did not mention what is the error. But what may cause is "$catlist .= '<h2>'.the_title().'</h2>';"

Try replacing 'the_title()' with **get_the_title()**

Comment: while what you're saying isn't what caused the error, it should be get_the_title(). that is true.  What helped was that It pointed out that I had a close php right above that.  Thanks!

Comment: lol I totally missed that! I was looking within the loop and totally overlooked that! my bad.

Comment: post it, i'll give you the answer credit

Comment: After calling `$query->the_post();` you add a closing PHP tag but you never open it again. It's a basic PHP syntax error, I strongly recommend setting up a code editor that auto-checks PHP syntax

Comment: yes. he already figured that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a part in your code that may cause error:

```
$catlist .= '<h2>'.the_title().'</h2>';
```

Try replacing with

```
$catlist .= '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>';
```

**Explanation:** *the_title()* echo the title of the post. But in your case you are using it within a function that will return the value. So you have to use *get_the_title()* instead. Thanks.

Note: also there is a closed php tag right before that line which is never open again. That surely causing the error.

Comment: the problem was indeed the close tag.